# Man pages from custom location

Tags: manpage

When I build some source in custom location, i.e.:

```
configure --prefix=$HOME/.local
```

and then, make install..., man pages are copied in ~/.local/share/man/ but inaccessible from `man` command

How can I make `man` recognise pages in my custom location?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For one-off manpage reading, just point `man` at the specific file:

```
man ~/.local/share/man/manX/manpage.1.gz
```

Otherwise, if you want to always check `~/.local/share`, then set the `MANPATH` environment variable for your user session (typically in your `.bashrc` file). To check what the current `MANPATH` is, do:

```
manpath
```

you'll probably want to append `:$HOME/local/.share/man` to the end of that.

Comment: Thanks. Interestingly `MANPATH` has already `$HOME/.local/man` but not `$HOME/.local/share/man`. I added `export MANPATH=$HOME/.local/share/man:$MANPATH` in .bashrc

Comment: running `manpath --debug` shows that it tries to add for every path entry the path one step down with `man` and `share/man` and adds them to the path *if* the folder exists. So e.g. if you have `$HOME/.local/bin` in path (which seems to be some kind of default nowadays?), I can get `$HOME/.local/man` and `$HOME/.local/share/man` added, if these folders exist.